# How do I exclude something from an "if" statement in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, web, google-cloud-platform, mobile-website

I am using the same ip address for many websites, so they all share the same index. So, I made all requests redirect to the main domain, as long as its not the main domain. This works just fine. My problem, is that now I made a mobile version of my website. Now, every time someone goes to the mobile website, it redirects them forever, from the main page, to the mobile one.
Here's what I have so far:

```js
var loc = window.location.href + '';
if (loc.indexOf('https://maindomain.com') - false); {
  window.location.replace("https://maindomain.com")
}
language = "JavaScript" >
  if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    window.location.replace("https://mobilewebsite.com")
  }
```

Comment: `loc.indexOf('https://maindomain.com')-false`??? a number minus false is just that number, since false is considered zero when doing subtraction - and since `indexOf` returns `-1` (which is truthy) when the string isn't found, you're basically redirecting to domain if the domain is the domain you redirect to ... try `loc.indexOf('https://maindomain.com') < 0` instead - and then read how indexOf works

Comment: Plus there is a `;` after the `if` condition, so that test isn't even used.

Comment: Also, please try to format your code for readability -- many users will give up at having to read something that requires that much scrolling in a single line.